# How can I remove element header, sidebar and footer from a specific view file in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp

I want to create separate designs for the admin login and register pages with different a header and footer.

I want to remove the commonly loaded header, sidebar, and footer from those pages.

Comment: Sounds like you need a [different layout](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#layouts).

Comment: thank you sir for your link and response i have solved my problem with it. thank you so much